# Azure stream analytics query - how to set even timestamp based on a javascript udf function?

Tags: azure-stream-analytics

I am timestamping data stream input events by a property "TS" in the message. However before I timestamp it using TS, I want to ensure that TS is ISO8601 compliant. If TS is not ISO8601 ocmpliant, I want to use EventEnqueuedUtcTime which is the arrival time of the message as timestamp.

My query looks something like this

```
SELECT 
  T.*
FROM
  input TIMESTAMP BY PARTITION BY PartitionId TIMESTAMP BY udf.getEventTimestamp(T)
```

Here `udf.getEventTimestamp(T)` returns the TS property in message(T) if it is ISO8601-compliant otherwise it will return EventEnqueuedUtcTime( arrival time of message in Iot Hub).

Running this script locally gives me the exception - 
`Error : Unexpected hosted function call`

I also tried to use `CASE` construct to accomplish this

```
SELECT 
  T.*
FROM
  input TIMESTAMP BY PARTITION BY PartitionId TIMESTAMP BY
  CASE
    WHEN udf.isValid(T.TS) THEN T.TS
    ELSE T.EventEnqueuedUtcTime 
  END
```

where `udf.isValid(T.TS)` returns true if the property TS is a valid ISO8601 compliant timestamp.

Again running this  locally returns - `Error : Unexpected hosted function call`

As per Microsoft Azure docs, `After you add a JavaScript user-defined function to a job, you can use the function anywhere in the query, like a built-in scalar function`

Does this mean that we cannot use udfs in TIMESTAMP BY and CASE constructs?
Can you suggest any workaround?

Answer (score 2):

At this time we can't use UDF within the TIMESTAMP BY clause.
However we case use [TRY_CAST](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/stream-analytics-query/try-cast-azure-stream-analytics) to solve your requirement.
Here's the query with the workaround:

```
 SELECT 
 T.*
 FROM
 input PARTITION BY PartitionId TIMESTAMP BY
   CASE
     WHEN TRY_CAST(T.TS AS DateTime) is not null THEN T.TS
     ELSE T.EventEnqueuedUtcTime 
   END
```

Let me know if you have any further question.

Thanks,

JS

Comment: Thanks, I have changed the query to look similar to your answer. Thanks for the help!